# NDSolve not returning the expected solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to simulate a simple circuit with Mathematica. 
The equation of the circuit is $R \dfrac{dQ}{dt} + \dfrac{Q(t)}{C} = f_{sig}(t)$.

This is the definition of $f_{sign}$, and the function seems to work, since the plot is good.

```
newfSign[t_] := 
  If[OddQ[Floor[t/τ]], 1/2*Subscript[V, max] (Cos[2*π *β*t/τ] + 1), Subscript[V, max]]
```

[image: Plot of $f_{sign}]

This is the definition of the solution:

```
s = NDSolve[{R*Q'[t] + Q[t]/C2 == newfSign[t], Q[0] == 0}, Q, {t, 0, 4 τ}]
```

And I try to plot it with this command:

```
Plot[Q[t]/C2 /. s, {t, 0, 4 τ}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Getting this result, which is not what would be expected, given the forcing function $f_{sign}$.

[image: Plot of NDSolve]

Those are the values I'm using:

```
Subscript[V, max] = 5
β = 10
τ = 500*10^-6
R = 2000
C2 = 0.22*10^-6
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please include the values for all your variables

Comment: Added just now.

Comment: It could be helpful to look at the difference of this solution with a solution for a f_sig(t) with a constant value of Subscript[V, max]. Also try to increase the PrecisionGoal parameter in case the effect of the inhomogeneity is very small and PlotPoints for the Plot of the solution. I would also suggest to try it with fixed step size (Method -> {"FixedStep", Method->...} , see doc) with a sufficiently small step size, maybe 10^-6 or smaller to ensure that the automatic determination of the step size is not the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `NDSolve` is not `HoldAll` or `HoldFirst`.  Therefore the differential equation is evaluated symbolically before it is passed to `NDSolve`.  Thus the differential equation that `NDSolve` sees is

```
{R*Q'[t] + Q[t]/C2 == newfSign[t], Q[0] == 0}
(* {4.54545*10^6 Q[t] + 2000 Derivative[1][Q][t] == 5, Q[0] == 0}  *)
```

The reason that one does not see the `If[OddQ..` bit of code is that `OddQ` always returns `False` if the argument is not an odd integer.  The symbolic expression `Floor[t / τ]` is not an odd integer.

The fix, explained in [What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/26037#26037) is to use `?NumericQ`:

```
ClearAll[newfSign];

newfSign[t_?NumericQ] := 
 If[OddQ[Floor[t/\[Tau]]], 
  1/2*Subscript[V, max] (Cos[2*\[Pi]*\[Beta]*t/\[Tau]] + 1), 
  Subscript[V, max]]
```

One way to make sure that a rapidly oscillating integrand is sampled enough is to limit the step size to be less than a quarter period using the `MaxStepSize` option:

```
s = NDSolve[{R*Q'[t] + Q[t]/C2 == newfSign[t], Q[0] == 0}, 
  Q, {t, 0, 4 τ}, MaxStepSize -> 1/(4*β/τ)]

Plot[Q[t]/C2 /. s, {t, 0, 4 τ}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 4):

For me it looks like the OddQ function behaves unexpected

If it is replaced by

```
OddQ2[n_] := If[Mod[n, 2] == 1, True, False]
```

then

```
s = NDSolve[{R*Q'[t] + Q[t]/C2 == newfSign[t], Q[0] == 0}, Q, {t, 0, 4 \[Tau]}]
Plot[Q[t]/C2 /. s, {t, 0, 4 \[Tau]}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

outputs

[image]

As I stated in my comment, for functions with fast oscillations there are sometimes problems with automatic step size evaluation.

using

```
s = NDSolve[{R*Q'[t] + Q[t]/C2 == newfSign[t], Q[0] == 0}, Q, {t, 0, 4 \[Tau]}, Method -> {"FixedStep", Method -> "ExplicitRungeKutta"}, "StartingStepSize" -> 10^-7, WorkingPrecision -> 10, MaxSteps -> 100000]
```

you get

[image]

which looks more reasonable.

I' curious **why** the OddQ function behaves like this and hope anyone has an idea.